# Itô for a pure jump martingale and preservable quadratic variation as compensator of quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

So, assuming $M$ is a pure (càdlàg) jump martingale, we get
$$[M,M]_t = \sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} (\Delta M_s)^2.$$
Of course the continous part $[M,M]_t^c$ of $[M,M]_t$ is exactly zero. That means by Meyer-Itô we get

$$M_t^2 = M_0^2 +\int_0^t 2 M_{s-}^2 dM_s+\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} \left[ M_s^2 - M_{s-}^2 - 2 M_{s-}\Delta M_s \right]  $$

So because $M$ is a pure jump martingale we get $$\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} \left[ M_s^2 - M_{s-}^2 \right]= M_t^2 - M_0^2,$$
right? 
But with
$$ \int_0^t 2 M_{s-}^2 dM_s = \sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t}2 M_{s-}\Delta M_s$$
we would get

$$M_t^2 = M_t^2$$

Okay, this is true... But I hoped to use that for showing that the compenssator of $[M,M]$ is teh same as the one of $M^2$...

EDIT:
So I just solved it... Seems like I was confused :-)

So define the preservable quadratic variation $\langle M, M \rangle $ of $M$ as the unique adapted preservable process of finite variation with non-decreasing paths for which $M^2- \langle M, M \rangle$ is a (local) martingale (existence and uniqueness is secured by the Doob-Meyer-Decomposition.

So with
$$\left( \Delta M_s \right)^2 =\Delta \left( M_s^2 \right)- 2M_{ s^- }\Delta M_s $$
and Itô we get
$$
M_t^2- M_0^2 = 2 \int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s} + \sum_{ i: \tau_i \leq t}  \left[ M_{\tau_i}^2 - M_{\tau_i - }^2 - 2 M_{\tau_i -} \Delta M_{\tau_i}   \right]
 \\=2 \int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s} + \sum_{ i: \tau_i \leq t} \left( \Delta M_{\tau_i} \right)^2
 =\int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s} + [M,M]_t.
$$
which implies
$$[M,M]_t= M_t^2- M_0^2-2 \int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s}$$
and so the compensator of $[M,M]$ must be the one of $M_t^2- M_0^2$ because the one of $\int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s}$ is zero (it is a local martingale and following Doob-Meyer they are unique).

So it is possible to define $ \langle M, M \rangle$ as the unique adapted preservable process of finite variation with non-decreasing paths for which
$$\left[ M,M \right]- \langle M, M \rangle$$
is a (local) martingale.

And the fun fact is: If we have a martingale which is not a pure jump martingale, we would get 
$$
M_t^2- M_0^2 = 2 \int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s}+ [M,M]_t^c + \sum_{ i: \tau_i \leq t}  \left[ M_{\tau_i}^2 - M_{\tau_i - }^2 - 2 M_{\tau_i -} \Delta M_{\tau_i}   \right]
 \\=2 \int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s} + + [M,M]_t^c+ \sum_{ i: \tau_i \leq t} \left( \Delta M_{\tau_i} \right)^2
 =\int_0^t M_{s-} d{M_s} + [M,M]_t.
$$
which would give us the same result!

Comment: are you sure about this : $\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} (\Delta M_s)^2=\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} \left[ M_s^2 - M_{s-}^2 - 2 M_{s-}\Delta M_s \right]$ I would rather go for :  $\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} (\Delta M_s)^2=\sum_{ 0\leq s \leq t} \left[ M_s^2 - M_{s-}^2 - 2 M_{s-}.M_s \right]$

Comment: Of course what you say is correct, but I never used that. What I used was Itô like on p.78 in Protters Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations. So:
$f( X_t)-f(X_0)= \int_0^t f'(X_{s-}) d X_s + \frac12 \int_0^t f''(X_{s-}) d[X,X]_s^c + \sum_{ 0<s<t} \left[ f(X_s) -f(X_{s-}) - f'(X_{s-}) \Delta X_s \right]$ 
And that is what I used... Or not?

Comment: Ahhh, saw my problem... What I get is $M_t^2=M_t^2$...

Comment: So I just added a few results which were the reason why I calculated this!